# How do I refresh Webview everytime the app is brought back from background?

Tags: java, android, android-webview

I have a webview application, and I need to refresh(using webview.Reload()) the webview whenever the app has been running in the background (has not been killed)  and is brought back.How would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*As a user navigates through, out of, and back to your app, the Activity instances in your app transition through different states in their lifecycle. The Activity class provides a number of callbacks that allow the activity to know that a state has changed: that the system is creating, stopping, or resuming an activity, or destroying the process in which the activity resides.*

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    webView.reload();
}
```

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle